# How to calculate amount of RAM required for serving X N-dimensional vectors with pgvector (HNSW)?

Tags: postgresql, vector-database, pgvector, vector-search

I'm trying to determine a function `f(x, n)` where `x` is the number of vectors and `n` is the number of vector dimensions such that for any `x`, `n`, `f(x, n)` is greater that the required amount of RAM to serve these vectors via a pgvector database with HNSW index.

I did some googling, but

1. I can't find a formula for index size.
2. I see that some databases (like Qdrant) can use memory-mapped files for both vectors and indices to reduce RAM consumption, but I don't see such options for pgvector. Does it require to store the whole HNSW index in memory? If not, how to determine the required amount of memory?

[This article](https://www.crunchydata.com/blog/hnsw-indexes-with-postgres-and-pgvector) says:

> The third trade-off for HNSW indexes is that they are sizable — the index for 1M rows of AI embeddings can be 8GB or larger. For performance reasons, you’ll want all of this index in memory.

although in [this article](https://qdrant.tech/articles/memory-consumption/) Qdrant that uses the same HNSW indexing algorithm is said to only require ~1GB RAM for serving 1 million vectors (without memory mapping). Why such difference?

Comment: "Why such difference?"  You first link seems to reference 1536 dimensional data, and the second one references 100 dimensional data.  I don't know the details of HNSW, but I would expect this to make a difference.